# Mono framework - dnsapi.dll missing

Tags: macos, mono

I'm trying to debug a Mono framework project on OSX targeting ASP .NET 4.5

I'm referencing the Microsoft Exchange Web Service Managed API in order to connect to my exchange server, and I guess at some point the dnsapi.dll file is required. I've searched all over my machine and I'm unable to find any libdnsapi.so, libdnsapi.a or libdnsapi.dylib

Any ideas why I am missing this library / where i can obtain it from?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was just to grab - https://github.com/toots/osx-i586-mingw32/blob/master/i586-mingw32/lib/libdnsapi.a - move it to /usr/local/lib and make sure that mono was including that location for resolving libraries.